# Wrong file reported as being used

Tags: windows, dll, wix

the following problem is beyond my knowledge:

1. On my Windows machine I'm trying to uninstall the application.
2. Uninstaller reported that I need to close TotalCommander before continuing.
3. The application I want to uninstall has nothing to do with TotalCommander.
4. The only thing that connects my application and TotalCmmander is the library named msvcp120.dll that is used by both my aplication and TotalComader.
5. The difference is that TotalCommander uses the msvcp120.dll located in system directory (c:\Windows\Wystem32\msvcp120.dll) and my application uses library with the same name in completely different directory (c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Ares\TestApp\msvcp120.dll). I have checked this in ProcessExplorer.
6. I've checked both TotalCommander and my application - both of them really load the library from different locations.
7. In my installer (I'm using Wix) I tried to disable InstallValidate action, but have ran into additional problems.

What I want to try now is to find out why am I being asked to close TotalComander when it has no obvious connection with the aplication I want to uninstall.

The following is the part of msi log file:

MSI (s) (C0:3C) [09:46:22:634]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1603 
Info 1603.The file C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Ares\TestApp\msvcp120.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: explorer, Id: 4032, Window Title: '(not determined yet)'.  Close that application and retry.
MSI (s) (C0:3C) [09:46:22:635]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (C0:3C) [09:46:22:635]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1603 
Info 1603.The file C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Ares\TestApp\msvcp120.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: TOTALCMD64, Id: 11352, Window Title: '(not determined yet)'.  Close that application and retry.
MSI (s) (C0:3C) [09:46:22:635]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (C0:3C) [09:46:22:635]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1603 
Info 1603.The file C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Ares\TestApp\msvcp120.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: TestApp, Id: 12056, Window Title: '(not determined yet)'.  Close that application and retry.

Here I can see that the C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Ares\TestApp\msvcp120.dll library is reported as being held by explorer, TotalCommander and my TestApp, but I'm asked to close only TotalCommander.

Thanks for any answer.